# if statement takes same path every time; possible str v. int conflict

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm working on a program that asks the user to pick one of two caves to enter. User may pick either cave 1 or cave 2. That number is compared to the answer (generated by random.randint (1,2)). If the user's choice is equal to the answer, he wins; else, he loses. The issue is that the program never branches to the win condition. No matter what choice user makes, he always loses. I've tried debugging but I cannot see the variable comparison values between caveAnswer and caveChoice.

```
def gameCore (name):
    print ('You stand before the entrances of two caves.')
    print ('Choose a cave, either cave 1 or cave 2.')
    print ( )


    caveAnswer = random.randint (1,2)
    caveChoice = input ('Enter either 1 or 2. ')


    if caveAnswer == caveChoice:  [# I suspect the problem occurs at this comparison]
        print ('You enter the black mouth of the cave and...')
        time.sleep (1)
        print ( )
        print ('You find a hill of shining gold coins!')
        playAgain (name)

    else:
        print ('You enter the black mouth of the cave and...')
        time.sleep(1)
        print ( ) 
        print ('A wave of yellow-orange fire envelopes you. You\'re toast.')
        playAgain (name)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yay. Now, *confirm* the assumption in the REPL: `1 == "1"`. So, *what* could be done to make both sides "of a compatible type"? (See [5.9 Comparisons](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/comparisons.html) as well:  "Otherwise [if not numbers], objects of different types [..] compare unequal.")

Comment: as a further hint. Try `print( (type(caveAnswer), type(caveChoice)) )`

Comment: Arg, old link in my previous comment (I blame google "feeling lucky"). Current for 2.x is http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in (this version has nicer formatting and also discusses protocol behavior)

Comment: @pst: It's pretty clear the OP is using 3.x—otherwise, `input` would have returned the number `1`, not the string `"1"`, and he wouldn't have had this problem in the first place. (Also, `print ( )` would print "()" instead of a blank line, etc.) So, if you're going to update the link, you probably should give the [3.x version](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: @Fluxcapacitor: A few minor notes. First, you usually don't want to escape apostrophes and quotes like that; you can use, e.g., `"A wave of yellow-orange fire envelopes you. You're toast."`Second, don't put blank spaces between function names and parentheses, or inside them—doing so with `print` is likely part of the reason that many of the answerers didn't realize you were using Python 3.

Comment: One more thing: When you ask a question here, it's worth explicitly mentioning that you're using Python 3. A lot of old-timers (meaning many of the people who know the answers to your questions) will immediately assume Python 2 if you don't say otherwise; the rest of us will look at your code and try to guess, and it may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
caveChoice = int(input ('Enter either 1 or 2. '))
```

You should also make it so that it'll try again if it's not an int.

Answer (score 3):

You should convert the input to an int:

```
caveChoice = int(input('Enter either 1 or 2. '))
```

But if you don't want the program to crash upon an input of, say, `'foo'`, then you need a `try-except` block, itself inside a `while` loop, so you can try again.

```
while True:
    try:
        caveChoice = int(input('Enter either 1 or 2. '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Try again.')
```

Also, you might want to check if the input is actually `1` or `2`.

```
while True:
    try:
        caveChoice = int(input('Enter either 1 or 2. '))
        if caveChoice not in (1, 2):
            raise ValueError
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input. Try again.')
```

Comment: This is the "make it so that it'll try again if it's not an int" I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your program ant it definitely works. To test it, just print out `caveAnswer` before entering your input `caveChoice`. If your have an error, then not in this function.

```
import random,time
def gameCore (name):
    print ('You stand before the entrances of two caves.')
    print ('Choose a cave, either cave 1 or cave 2.')
    print ( )


    caveAnswer = random.randint (1,2)
    print caveAnswer
    caveChoice = input ('Enter either 1 or 2. ')

    if caveAnswer == caveChoice:  
        print 'You enter the black mouth of the cave and - answer=%d - your answer=%d' % (caveAnswer, caveChoice)
        time.sleep (1)
        print ( )
        print 'You find a hill of shining gold coins!'
        # playAgain (name) 

    else:  
        print ('You enter the black mouth of the cave and - answer=%d - your answer=%d')% (caveAnswer, caveChoice)
        time.sleep(1)
        print ( ) 
        print ('A wave of yellow-orange fire envelopes you. You\'re toast.')
        # playAgain (name)

gameCore('Test')
```

Comment: Yes definitely! I mean just copy paste it and run it two or three times..

Comment: I think Python 2 supports int/string comparisons, but Python 3 doesn't. The OP's problem is in Python 3 because `print` is a function.

Comment: @Volatility `1 == "1"` is false in Python 2.x *and* Python 3.x

Comment: I've run it 10 times but it never branches to gold coins. I'm stumped. My logic looks solid. There's some rule w/python I'm overlooking.

Comment: For me it works in Python 2 (import the print function) but not Python 3.

Comment: @Volatility the point is that if you enter a `int` value, then `input` converts it to int. If you give a string without quotes, it will handle it as variable. So no need to cast here..

Comment: @Fluxcapacitor what version of python are you using? I tested it with 2.7.2

Comment: Oh yeah, that is right.You guys are mixing up `input` and `raw_input`. I don't know why my answer worked though, and his original question didn't work.

Comment: @forivall: The original one works in 2.x, but not 3.x. Your answer works in both 2.x and 3.x because the extra `int()` is harmless in 2.x—`input` will return the integer `1`, and then `int(1)` is still the integer `1`.

Comment: Yeah; I phrased my comment wrong, I do know that the extra int() is harmless. I did forget that the original `input` was removed in py3k, and `raw_input` renamed to `input`. Thanks! -- now I think about it, he used print like a function in every case, so I should have figured that he's using python 3.

Comment: @forivall: It's not just using `print` like a function, but using `print()` to print a blank line. While this code and yours "work" in 2.0, the output is clearly not what the OP intended. (At least I don't remember any text adventures printing empty tuples in place of blank lines, not even the really bad PET ports of Scott Adams games…)

Answer (score -1):

Try converting to int.

caveChoice = input ('Enter either 1 or 2. ')

Comment: This doesn't do what you say. In fact, it's identical to the OP's existing code, so it doesn't really do _anything_ useful.